# AngularJS controller for main menu

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way to handle the functionality of html that is global to an application? Should I just put an ng-controller on the navigation element to handle the logout and login?

```
<body>
   <div class="nav"></div>
   <div class="view-container" ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller** is a set of javacscript functions bound to **scope** that refers to app **model**. If you want the navigation to have the particular control you can just define it there.

```
 <div class="nav" ng-controller="YourController"></div>
```